# How to map one property to another with Knockout Mapping?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have the model defined as

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

and a ViewModel in JS as

```
var vm = {
   name : ko.observable()
}
```

Also, I have callback which should update the viewmodel:

```
function callback(data)
{
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, viewModel);
}
```

But for ko.mapping plugin property 'name' not equals 'Name'.

How to define mapping from 'Name' to 'name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to specify the `name` property in the viewModel as the mapping plugin will add it for you.

And for the casing, alter your serialization convention to lowercase the properties.

Or, you can do what I have done and accept the uppercase in your view model. Even though it doesn't sit too well with common Javascript conventions, I have accepted it as the "properties that come from the server".

I have found it pretty handy to know which ones are created from the mapping and which ones I use for view model things. Of course, you will not see the server generated / mapped properties in your view model but they will be there.

I use this to specify and create server side view models on the server, serialize them and map them to my knockout models. This way I can concentrate only on behaviour in my knockout view models.

If you need to convert any server side object to a javascript "object", you can implement that conversion in the mapping object, like I do [here](https://github.com/MikeEast/StringConvert.com/blob/master/StringConvert.WebClient/Views/index.cshtml#L47)

Comment: Ok, I see.
But, can I specify by adding attributes for JSON serializer to serialize my server-side properties according to naming conventions on client-side?